# Spring boot & MariaDB - Make a complex query with repository (prepared statement and variables)

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I want to make the following query in my REST API (with Spring boot) :

(my query works on a MySQL console)

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(t.type=',type,',value,0)) AS "',type,'"'))
    INTO @sql FROM transfers;
    SET @sql = CONCAT(
        'SELECT t.date,SUM(t.value) AS "-1",',
        @sql,
        'FROM transfers t GROUP BY t.date ORDER BY t.date DESC'
    );
    SELECT @sql;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

Is it possible ?
I tried to implement it in my repo :

```
    @Query(value = "SET @sql = NULL;\n" +
        "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(t.type=',type,',value,0)) AS \"',type,'\"'))\n" +
        "INTO @sql FROM transfers;\n" +
        "SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t.date, SUM(t.value) AS \"-1\",',@sql,\n" +
        "'FROM transfers t GROUP BY t.date ORDER BY t.date DESC');\n" +
        "PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;\n" +
        "EXECUTE stmt;", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> getBalanceDatasets();
```

I got this error at startup :

> Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List fr.kdoolaeghe.savingsaccount.repository.TransferRepository.getBalanceDatasets()! Reason: The string <SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(t.type=',type,',value,0)) AS "',type,'"'))
> INTO @sql FROM transfers;
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t.date, SUM(t.value) AS "-1",',@sql,
> 'select count(t) FROM transfers t GROUP BY t.date
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;> starts a quoted range at 193, but never ends it.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The string <SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(t.type=',type,',value,0)) AS "',type,'"'))
> INTO @sql FROM transfers;
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t.date, SUM(t.value) AS "-1",',@sql,
> 'select count(t) FROM transfers t GROUP BY t.date
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;> starts a quoted range at 193, but never ends it.

EDIT:

I tried to divide the query in two requests as followed :

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT t.date,:headers,SUM(t.value) AS 'total'\n" +
        "FROM transfers t GROUP BY t.date ORDER BY t.date DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> getBalanceDatasets(@Param("headers") String headers);

@Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(\n" +
        "'SUM(IF(t.type=',type,',value,0)) AS \"type',type,'\"')) FROM transfers),'NULL')", nativeQuery = true)
String getBalanceTypeHeaders();
```

getBalanceTypeHeaders() method works but second method getBalanceDatasets() integrate the String with apostrophe (") symbols.

It results in a wrong column.. Any idea to solve that ?